# I want to draw 2 rectangles that superimpose on one another with Windows.FillRect

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to draw 2 rectangles that superimpose on one another. One of which I want it a smaller size(A) than the other one (B) so that I can view the one at the back(B).

[image: A is in Black and B is in aqua colour]

```
procedure DrawRectangle(drawDC:HDC;cellBrush:TBrush);
var
    gridCellRect, gridCellRect1  :Trect ;   
begin
    gridCellRect.Top := 75;
    gridCellRect.Bottom := 150;
    gridCellRect.Left  := 192;
    gridCellRect.right := 200; 
    SetBkMode(drawDC, OPAQUE);
    cellBrush.color := claqua;

    Windows.FillRect(DrawDC, gridCellRect, cellBrush.Handle);

    gridCellRect1 := gridCellRect;
    // I tried to modify the top position to make it visible
    gridCellRect1.Top := gridCellRect -5; 
    cellBrush.color := clBlack;
    Windows.FillRect(DrawDC, gridCellRect, cellBrush.Handle);
end;
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  You already know how to draw rectangles.  Just draw the black one, then shrink + offset the rectangle and draw the blue one. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your colors reversed (you're drawing in the wrong order), your `gridCellRect.Left` and `gridCellRect.Right` are far too narrow (8 pixels), and you don't need the call to `SetBkMode` at all.

In addition, you've got an error in `gridCellRect - 5` (which won't even compile), and you never try to draw to the rectangle defined in `gridCellRect1` even if it did. (Your second call to `FillRect` uses `gridCellRect` instead of `gridCellRect1`.)

Here's a corrected version of the code that should get you started:

```
procedure DrawRectangle(drawDC:HDC;cellBrush:TBrush);
var
  gridCellRect, gridCellRect1  :Trect ;
begin
  gridCellRect.Top := 75;
  gridCellRect.Bottom := 150;
  gridCellRect.Left  := 125;    // Changed left and right to widen
  gridCellRect.right := 200;
  cellBrush.color := clBlack;
  Windows.FillRect(DrawDC, gridCellRect, cellBrush.Handle);

  gridCellRect1 := gridCellRect;
  gridCellRect1.Top := gridCellRect.Top + 5;
  gridCellRect1.Bottom := gridCellRect.Bottom - 5;
  cellBrush.color := clAqua;
  Windows.FillRect(DrawDC, gridCellRect1, cellBrush.Handle);
end;
```

Tested with

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DrawRectangle(Canvas.Handle, Canvas.Brush);
end;
```